# Multiple circle lines with gradient color CSS

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I want achieve design of banner with multiple circle lines with gradient background color. I've research more regarding this. I'm unable to find questions related my concern.

[image]

Bellow code is used to create solid color background banner.

```
.blue-cross-banner{
    background: #0FA2EB;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 4em;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

I cannot upload svg format of banner. It shows the gradient shade color of circle lines.
I found some what related to my question in here https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/.
But it doesn't help to my concern.

```
#grad2 {
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(15, 162, 235, 0) 33.16%, #0FA2EB 85.35%);
border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Above css is need to use background gradient color of circle lines.

Comment: Use two gradients. The second should be a repeating radial one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any samples for create repeating radial circles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0 20px, blue 21px 23px);
  clip-path: circle(farthest-side); /* to cut extra circles*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```